# Android textView disappears when clicked

Tags: android, onclick, textview

I have a TextView with the android:onClick attribute.  When clicked, the TextView disappears.  I don't want the TextView to disappear when clicked.  Any ideas?

**Edit:**

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"android:text="Click Me!"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="processClick"
android:clickable="true"/>
```

http://i1179.photobucket.com/albums/x386/jenningsr2006/unclicked.png

http://i1179.photobucket.com/albums/x386/jenningsr2006/clicked.png

**Edit**

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.example);

    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1111);
    t.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // Do some job here
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Clicking it does the operation correctly, that's not the problem.  When I "mousedown" on the TextView, it disappears, then reappears on "mouseup".

Comment: Please post some more details about your layout and your code. Where do you think is your problem and how exactly it looks like.

Comment: Post the code with the processClick definition.

Answer (score 4):

I thought I had the same problem but it turned out the textview was not dissapearing, rather the color was changing so that it was the same as the background color. Thus it appeared hidden but it really was there. You can set the clicked color of the text view by setting it's color state list resource

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Comment: Just setTextColor() then the TextView will be the color you set. If you didn's setTextColor(), the text color will change with clicked color when you clicked it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered a method `processClick`? There is no need to do it this way. Remove the `clickable` property and also `onClick` property. More simple approach is to set onClick listener from the code, for example in onCreate method:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(textView1);
text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // Do some job here

    }
});
```

The view becomes `clickable` automatically when you set an on click listener. Good luck

Comment: That way works the same as what I had.  Still disappears when I click on it.

Comment: to what do you have in your onClick method / in your processClick method?