# LinearLayout with background does not show child all views

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have `LinearLayout` with background which is selector.
In this layout there are other `Views` `ImageView` and `LinearLayout` with two `TextView` but this `TextViews` are not displayed.
Here is the `layout xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="@drawable/category_item"
    android:padding="6dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toptext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the selector code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/category_clicked" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/category_norm"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: So all answers are wrong ? If not accept one..

Answer (score 1):

I've tryied this layout and it shows your text views. Maybe text that you are setting to them are empty. Just check this.

And remove this `android:layout_weight="1"` from here :

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/toptext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```

its useles.

Comment: Removed but nothing I am using this layout as item in `listView` and it begin not to work after setting background (selector), and if the background is just image it shows texts only when layout is clicked

Comment: You need to change your text color. I think thay just imposed.

Comment: Nope color is ok changed it and nothing happened

Comment: Look on this post, the same issue that you has.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458408/android-textview-disappears-when-clicked

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="@drawable/category_item"
     android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip" >
```

android:orientation="vertical" is probably missing

Comment: added, but did not change anything at all. I have problems only viewing `TextBox` textes

Comment: try setting the height of textviews to fill parent as well

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

either remove this from all widget. Or use this in all childs.. (imageView, inner linearlayout, two textViews)

Comment: Removed it but layout just got taller, changed `layout_width` to `wrap_content` it now has good height but texts are still missing

Comment: also in imageview 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" ... use wrap_content

Comment: @StinePike, can you give explaination about why weight should be added to all widgets ?

Comment: @yakiv .. it is better to not using weight. but if he wants to make those equal then he can use weight in all